# Can I automate a click on this link using applescript?

Tags: applescript, browser-automation

I'm writing an Applescript to automate four clicks on the "Organizr" page for one of my Flickr albums to change the order of my photos.  Three of the links have IDs, so automating those clicks is easy.  For example:

```
clickID3("comm_button_ok")
to clickID3(theId3)
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId3 & "').click();" in document 1
end tell
end clickID3
```

That works!

But how do I automate clicking on this link?

```html
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('random'); return false;">Randomly</a>
```

Here's the entire batch of code from the Flickr Organizr page for the menu that link resides in:

```html
<div class="candy_menu" id="candy_set_menu_arrange" style="display: block;">
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('date-taken-asc'); return false;">Arrange by date taken (oldest first)</a>
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('date-taken-desc'); return false;">Arrange by date taken (newest first)</a>
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('date-posted-asc'); return false;">Arrange by date uploaded (oldest first)</a>
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('date-posted-desc'); return false;">Arrange by date uploaded (newest first)</a>
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('title'); return false;">Alphabetically</a>
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('random'); return false;">Randomly</a>
<a href="#" onclick="_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('reverse'); return false;">Reverse current order</a>
</div>
```

I know how to automate the click to open the `candy_set_menu_arrange` menu.  But how do I automate the click on "Randomly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `anchor` element tag has an event attribute, `onclick`, which tells you exactly what occurs when the element is clicked. Therefore, since you can't issue a click yourself, you should just be able to forward the instructions from the `onclick` attribute (which is JavaScript code) straight to the *Safari* tab:

```
tell application "Safari" to tell the front document to do JavaScript ¬
    "_ge('tabl').tabl_get_active_one_set_mat().mat_resort('random'); return false;"
```

Failing that, you can always target the element using the [**`querySelector()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) method, which is a lot more powerful than `getElement...()` methods. I'll let you read the documentation to which I've linked for an overview of what it does, and then you can refer to the [**CSS Selector Reference**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) whenever you need to jog your memory on the specific syntax for targeting elements in the various possible ways. The way I'm going to demonstrate as one possible way you could target that anchor discriminates on the basis of its `onclick` attribute containing the word `"random"`, returning the first anchor element to satisfy this condition:

```
document.querySelector('a[onclick*="random"]').click();
```

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry if you responded to my query about the em space and deleted it after a reasonable time, however I haven't been able to return before now so not sure what the outcome was.  Briefly, would you say that using that character (or using it in the manner in which I do) is problematic ?